# Json array and object Parsing

Tags: android, json

Below is my JSON. I need to parse the news_title in the "newsdetail" from the category list object. What is the correct way to parse this data? please help me.

```
 {"categorylist":[{"process":"news","ncid":"1"","newsdetail":[{"newsid":"604","category":"1","category_title":"","news_title":"just"},{"newsid":"606","category":"1","category_title":"","news_title":"fg"}]},{"process":"news","ncid":"2","newsdetail":[{"newsid":"477","category":"2","category_title":"","news_title":"way},{"newsid":"478","category":"1","category_title":"","news_title":"k"}]}
```

Comment: you `JSON` is not valid . Varify here ->http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: Did you try anything yourself for parsing this json ?

Comment: Can I have a look at your code for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
{"categorylist":[{"process":"news","ncid":"1"" // cannot be double quotes come here. 
,"newsdetail":[{"newsid":"604","category":"1","category_title":"","news_title":"just"},{"newsid":"606","category":"1","category_title":"","news_title":"fg"}]},{"process":"news","ncid":"2","newsdetail":[{"newsid":"477","category":"2","category_title":"","news_title":"way},{"newsid":"478","category":"1","category_title":"","news_title":"k"}]}
```

you can use below parsor.. but your string data has some issue

```
 try {

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray category_list = jsonObject.getJSONArray("category_list");
                    for (int i = 0; i < category_list.length() ; i++) {
                        // here you get news title for each news
                        String newsTitle = category_list.getJSONObject(i).getString("news_title");
                    }


                }catch (JSONException e){

                }
```